# How to execute UPDATE stored procedure with %ROWTYPE

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

How to exec update stored procedure with %rowtype

```
PROCEDURE p_update (
    p_id     IN   t.id%TYPE,
    p_row    IN   t%rowtype) 
IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE t
    SET
        row = p_row
    WHERE
        id = p_id; 
END p_update;

declare 
t_row   t%rowtype;
t_id    t.id%type;
begin
t_row.name := 'TEST';
t_id := 10;
pck_api.p_update(t_row, t_id);
end;
```

I got PLS-00306 wrong number or types of arguments

Comment: your procedure accepts id as first argument and record as second, however in your anonymous block you pass record as first and id as second

Comment: Yes, it was error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `name` column to your rowtype(`p_row`) parameter `p_row.name` within the update stetment of your stored procedure `p_update` and change the order of arguments while invoking the stored procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_update (
    p_id     IN   t.id%TYPE,
    p_row    IN   t%rowtype) 
IS
BEGIN
  update t set name = p_row.name where id=p_id;
END;
/


Declare 
 t_row   t%rowtype;
 t_id    t.id%type;
Begin
 t_row.name := 'Test';
 t_id := 10;
 p_update(t_id,t_row);
End;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b7ee7ec92199e17139eb0f3ae35b172d)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. But, I want to use stored procedure

Comment: `p_update` is a stored procedure, what do you mean?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I think, I've fixed my explanation now.

Comment: Work well now. But, in procedure I have `update  t set ROW` which is for update all columns, how can I avoid that,  and keep `set ROW`

Comment: the statement already have a where restriction. Can you elaborate with an example @Pavlos04

Comment: When I run anonymous block, I got ORA-01400 cannot update t ('EMAIL', ...) to null

Comment: @Pavlos04 you should look up `not null` columns within the table then. Seems you're trying to update a column with `not null` constraint.